# Php script break in Middle for large files parsing

Tags: php, linux, cron, timeout

I am running the `cron` to update the inventory in our database from the ERP inventory csv file. The ERP inventory CSV file contains the `19K record` almost. Cron will pick up all records 1 by 1 and update the matched inventory in the database. But since a few days **among 19K records 13K-14k records only parse** by files and script break in the middle.

I have tried to run the script directly from browser also but its raised the same issue. No error is displayed in the error log.

I was thinking that its timeout issue and increases the `max_execution_time` to `1500 (25min)`. But the issue is not resolved yet.

Anyone can suggest me how to solve this issue? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check cron-log? Which operating system you are using?

Comment: I am using linux server. Yes I have check cron log no issue reported. Even I try to run on browser tab also but the same issue.

Comment: You may make log level up. Please see this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412805/crond-log-level-meaning

Answer (score 0):

> No error is displayed in the error log.

Then your first course of action is to [verify that your error logging](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) is working as expected. If it is a (PHP) timeout or a memory limit issue then the reason will be getting flagged - but it might not be getting reported.

You forgot to tell us *how* cron runs the task - is this via the CLI SAPI or are you using a http client (wget, curl etc) to invoke via the webserver? The SAPIs have very different behaviours and usually use seperate php.ini files.

> I was thinking that its timeout issue

Because you've checked and it always bombs out at the same interval after starting?

> But since a few days among 19K records 13K-14k records only parse

And previously it was taking less than the identified amount of time to complete?

> and increases the max_execution_time

How? In the script? In the (right) php.ini? Note that if the script is running via the webserver, then there may also be a timeout configured on the webserver.

You might consider prefixing your script with:

```
set_time_limit(3000);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

And capturing the stderr and stdout from the script.

Comment: Before also the same 19K records will be there and it was takes almost 20 mins to processed. but now only 13-14K processed and script end in almost 10-11 min. I have increase the max_execution_time from php.ini

Comment: Now I have remove the script from cron and running it on browser tabs but no change same result is displayed.

Comment: "19K records will be there and it was takes almost 20 mins to processed. but now only 13-14K processed and script end in almost 10-11 min" - then its *very* unlikely to be the timeout - so you changed the timeout. Hmmmm.

Comment: Sorry @symcbean I am not getting

Comment: Read my answer above. Test your error reporting. Apply the code changes to your script. Run the script. Read the logs and output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide csv in 2 files and execute the cron i think your csv file have a problem. if one of them execute without trouble then the process have not issue, repeat process to find the block with problem.
a few years i work with a interface wich read a file to export to SAP, sometimes one special character make the script break.